# Entity Framework: multiple dbcontext or not? And a few other performance related question

Tags: entity-framework-core, ienumerable, dbcontext, icollection, iasyncenumerable

I’m build a calendar/entry/statistics application using quite complex models with a large number of relationships between models.

In general I’m concerned of performance, and are considering different strategies and are looking for input before implementing the application.

I’m completely new to `DBContextPooling` so please excuse me for possible stupid questions. But has `DBContextPooling` anything to do with the use of multiple `DBContext` classes, or is the use related to improved performance regardless of a single or multiple `DBContext`?

I might end up implementing a larger number of `DBsets`, or should I avoid it? I’m considering to create multiple `DBContext` Classes for simplicity, but will this reduce memory use and improve performance? Would it be better/smarter to split the application into smaller projects?

Is there any performance difference in using `IEnumerable` vs `ICollection`? I’m avoiding the use of lists as much as possible. Or would it be even better to use `IAsyncEnumerable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your performance pain points will come from a complex architecture that you have not simplified.  Managing a monolithic application result in lots of unnecessary 'compensating' logic when one use case is treading on the toes of another and your relationships are so intertwined.

Optimisations such as whether to use Context Pooling or IEnumerable vs ICollection can come later.  They should not affect the architecture of your solution.

If your project is as complex as you suggest, then I'd recommend you read up on Domain Driven Design and Microservices and break your application up into several projects (or groups of projects).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/

Each project (or group of projects) will have its own DbContext to administer the entities within that project.
Further, each DbContext should start off by only exposing Aggregate Roots through the DbSets.  This can mean more database activity than is strictly necessary for a particular use case but best to start with a clean architecture and squeeze that last ounce of performance (sometimes at the cost of architectural clarity), if and when needed.

For example if you want to add an attendee to an appointment, it can be appealing to attack the Attendee table directly.  But, to keep things clean, and considering an attendee cannot exist without an appointment, then you should make appointment the aggregate root and only expose appointment as an entry point for the outside world to attack.  That appointment can be retrieved from the database with its attendees.  Then ask the appointment to add the attendees.  Then save the appointment graph by calling SaveChanges on the DbContext.

In summary, your Appointment is responsible for the functionality within its graph.  You should ask Appointment to add an Attendee to the list instead of adding an Attendee to the Appointment's list of attendees.  A subtle shift in thinking that can reduce complexity of your solution an awful lot.

The art is deciding where those boundaries between microservices/contexts should lie.  There can be pros and cons to two different architectures, with no clear winner

---

To your other questions:

DbContext Pooling is about maintaining a pool of ready-to-go instantiated DbContexts.  It saves the overhead of repeated DbContext instantiation.  Probably not worth it, unless you have an awful lot of separate requests coming in and your profiling shows that this is a pain point.

The number of DbSets required is alluded to above.

As for IEnumerable or ICollection or IList, it depends on what functionality you require.  Here's a nice simple summary ... https://medium.com/developers-arena/ienumerable-vs-icollection-vs-ilist-vs-iqueryable-in-c-2101351453db

> Would it be better/smarter to split the application into smaller
> projects?

Yes, absolutely!  Start with architectural clarity and then tweak for performance benefits where and when required.  Don't start with performance as the goal (unless you're building a millisecond sensitive solution).